# How can I know the max amount of indexes in Listview?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to know how many indexes I have in my listview but I can't get a way to know it.

Im currently developing a music player. The code presented here is the code i have to get the previous song playing but i cant do it if it is the first of the list so I'm trying to find a way to get to the last of the listview when u click previous and the selected one is the first.

The idea I had is to get the last index and redirect it to play it but I don't find a way to have the number of the last index

```
Dim g As Integer = ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)
If ListView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0 Then
    If g > 0 Then
        g -= 1
        ListView1.Items(g).Selected = True
        ListView1.Items(g).EnsureVisible()
        ListView1.Select()
        wp.URL = ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).SubItems(2).Text
        wp.controls.play()
        Label4.Text = "A tocar: " + ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).SubItems(0).Text
        g += 1
        ListView1.Items(g).Selected = False
        ListView1.Items(g).EnsureVisible()
    Else
        ListView1.Items(0).Selected = True
        ListView1.Items(0).EnsureVisible()
        ListView1.Select()
        wp.URL = ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(ListView1.SelectedIndices().Count)).SubItems(2).Text
        wp.controls.play()
        Label4.Text = "A tocar: " + ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices().Count).SubItems(0).Text
        g += 1
        ListView1.Items(g).Selected = False
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Note that VBA is not VB.NET please edit your tags to clarify which one you mean. Also please clarify what you mean by "indexes"? Amount of items in the list? Please clarify and show what you have tried so far. [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Comment: Can u please check it now

Comment: `ListView1.Items.Count` gives you the amount of items. Since indices start with `0` you have to subtract `1` from that count and you have the index of the last item.

Comment: Wrote it as an answer so you can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView1.Items.Count` gives you the amount of items. Since indices start with `0` you have to subtract `1` from that count and you have the index of the last item.

```
LastItemIndex = ListView1.Items.Count - 1
```